# What am I looking for when reviewing low-quality marked posts?

Tags: support, questions, review, moderation

Part of me wants to recommend incorrect or too short answers for deletion, but the community should take care of that part the other part of me says.

So, when checking low-quality content answers/questions what am I looking for (besides spam) that I should recommend for deletion? And what could be marked as "Looks Good" even if I know the answer is completely wrong or incomplete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's incorrect, down vote it and if it doesn't have the context needed, try to edit it.

For deletion, you can check the following

- comments as answers
- "Thanks"
- new questions as answers
- promotion
- link only answers that require the reader to dig through the link

Comment: so pretty much what I was already doing. K.

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be a Vote Up/Down on answers within the low-quality posts review section? I have to click into the question in order to downvote an answer.

Comment: @Dez the aim of that specific section is quality not necessarily correctness, if you need to do actions outside of what low quality review provides click through to the link. So "looks good" means "the quality looks good". Even if it is incorrect, you can still edit for spelling, grammatical errors and content.